# Swift how to dispatch_queue to update tableview cell

Tags: swift, dispatch-async

My app needs to fetching data from a server before loading the tableview.
How to using dispatch_async to make app updating the cell view after completing fetching data.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("editCell") as! EditTableViewCell

    cell.answerText.text = dictPicker[indexPath.row]![dictAnswer[indexPath.row]!]
    cell.questionView.text = listQuestion1[indexPath.row]
    cell.pickerDataSource = dictPicker[indexPath.row]!
    dictAnswer[indexPath.row] = cell.pickerValue
    cell.answerText.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddFollowUpViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEnd)
    cell.answerText.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.identifier = true

    return cell
}
```

When I used to above code, it gives me an error that: dictAnswer is nil. dictAnswer is fetched from server. I think the reason is the cell updated before dictAnswer fetched. But i do not know how to use the dispatch_async. I hope there are some can give me a hint. THX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your UITableViewDataSource functions should reference the number of rows in your array, like so

```
var data:[String]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    }
```

So in your async function to get the data you might do:

```
func loadData() {
     // some code to get remote data
     self.data = result
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
         tableView.reloadData()
     }
}
```

While your array is empty, (data.count returning 0) the tableView wont try to load any rows and crash

**Update for Swift 3+:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is how you reload data. But remember to refresh your Array before you
reload data. Remember that just fetching data is not important, updating data into array before reloading is also important

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

After using Scriptable's answer, I had to make some updates and thought it would be a good idea to post them back here...

**Swift 3**:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
```

and

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```